# Make a sample of react-monaco-editor in StackBlitz

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor, stackblitz, react-monaco-editor

I try to use https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor in StackBlitz.

Here is a very small sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mq152n?file=EditorBasic.tsx,index.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MonacoEditor from 'react-monaco-editor';

export default class EditorBasic extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <MonacoEditor
        width="400px"
        height="500px"
        options={{ minimap: { enabled: false }, lineNumbers: 'off' }}
        value="content"
        theme="vs-dark"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

But it returns an error `Cannot declare a const variable twice: 'process'.`.

I also googled some other projects with keywords `react-monaco-editor` and `StackBlitz`, none of them worked. For instance, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-monaco-editor-vggj5m?file=index.js returned the same error.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-monaco-editor-s6hwjf?file=index.js

I added `source-map-support` dependency which solves in my case